# Facebook API get number of posts?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Given a page access token, how can get the total number of posts day by day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the FQL insights table: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/

the insight you're looking for in in the Page Content section of that link.

However, that is an insight that is being deprecate on 2/15.  So be sure to get your data quick.  It's being removed from Facebook.  I don't know why.

Comment: Thank you. Bu as you say this is going to be deprecated soon, there is no other way of get this count?

Comment: Nope, Facebook is not commenting on a replacement.  Your best bet is to file a bug at http://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Answer (score 1):

You can only retrieve a summary/count for published posts on a page. Something like this will work when querying the Page directly:

```
{PAGE}?fields=published_posts.limit(1).summary(total_count).since(1)
```

The response will look something like:

```
{
    published_posts: {
        summary: {
            total_count: 12345
        },
        ...
    }
}
```

or if you want to query the `published_posts` directly, use:

```
{PAGE}/published_posts?limit=1&summary=total_count&since=1
```

The response will look something like:

```
{
    summary: {
        total_count: 12345
    },
    ...
}
```

Setting `limit` to 1 ensures that your query is not unnecessarily large. If you're just needing the total post count, then set `limit` to 1.

The `since` parameter is a unix timestamp (milliseconds since January 1, 1970) and is required to retrieve the total post count. Set this to 1 as setting it to 0 will throw an error.

More details: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/published_posts/

Comment: You can also set `limit` to 0, since you are not interested in the posts themselves